# How can fix the Jekyll installation error in termux?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, termux

I am having Jekyll installation error in termux on my android phone. When I am trying to install it's failing to build gem native extension for termux....Jekyll installation code in termux

Comment: this question should not be posted here

Comment: @pardeep perhaps it should be there? https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2340

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the [Termux Wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/List_of_Ruby_packages_known_to_work) has documented the following with Jekyll as an example:

> ### Instructions
>
> Firstly you need to install all packages in the "pkg requirements" row. Example for Jekyll:
>
> ```
> pkg install ruby clang make libffi
> ```
>
> Then you need to follow the special instructions. If no special instructions are given, you can install the package with:
>
> ```
> gem install jekyll
> ```
>
> Note (friendly reminder) for the gems that build native extensions make sure you have a build environment ready; a minimum can be achieved by running:
>
> ```
> pkg install autoconf build-essential
> ```

Comment: Try `gem install jekyll --version 3.8.6`

Comment: i ended up giving up. there were way too many problems to be resolved and worth the trouble. hope someone will do an app for this, eventually... or i'll just find a better solution! plus, termux was taking over 3gb already!! :D